with '[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsData', how to use it to check if clipboard has 'html' data format?
I am trying to figure out to use this class. I think I know how to get it to work when I want to check if the clipboard has a text format. With text copied, the following returns true:
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsData('text')

But if I copy a article with links from an article or a webpage, the following returns false:
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsData('html')

I know for sure I have html format in my clipboard, as I can paste it in software that allows me to do so, like Obsidian.
I am doing this as I want to get my clipboards content in html format. I tried the following:
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetData('text')

and it returns an object:
CanRead      : True
CanSeek      : True
CanWrite     : True
Capacity     : 2354
Length       : 2354
Position     : 0
CanTimeout   : False
ReadTimeout  :
WriteTimeout :

but doing the same thing with [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetData('html') returns nothing, again I am sure I have html content in my clipboard.
I need to do this as I simply need to get my clipboards html content as a string, for further processing in PowerShell. I am on pwsh 7.4

ContainsData and GetData is for specific binary formats. Whereas HTML is a text format, so try using ContainsText - and instead of using magic-strings like'text' or 'html' you should be using the named members in DataFormats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataformats?view=windowsdesktop-8.0


Use the static fields of the static [System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats] class to specify a well-known data format as the argument in a [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsData() call, specifically [System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Html in this case:
# Checks if HTML text (source code) has been copied to the clipboard.
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsData(
  [System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Html
)

Note that this tests for data that has been explicitly declared as representing HTML when it was copied - as notably happens when you select and copy text in a web browser - not just any string data that happens to be HTML.

Similarly, you can pass the same fields to the [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetData() method in order to retrieve a well-known format:
# Retrieves HTML text that has been copied to the clipboard
# as a [string] instance.
# If there is none, $null is returned.
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetData(
  [System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Html
)

Note that the resulting, multiline [string] includes metadata that precedes the raw HTML source code; for example:
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000225
EndHTML:0000000933
StartFragment:0000000261
EndFragment:0000000897
SourceURL:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataformats?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#fields
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><span style="color: rgb(22, 22, 22); font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, SegoeUI, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;">Use<span> </span></span><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>

